# installing Boost for CMake in OpenPose in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost, cmake

How should I install Boost for CMake in OpenPose in Ubuntu 20.04? The current way I have installed it throws an error:

```
$ cmake-gui ..
Error: could not load cache
6456/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2016] 07:23:06 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ make -j`nproc`
Scanning dependencies of target openpose_lib
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'openpose_lib'
[ 25%] No download step for 'openpose_lib'
[ 50%] No patch step for 'openpose_lib'
[ 50%] No update step for 'openpose_lib'
[ 62%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_lib'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system thread filesystem)
  (Required is at least version "1.54")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2179 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:107: caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I installed boost and still get an error:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev
[sudo] password for mona: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8ubuntu1.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libprotobuf-lite17 libprotoc17
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libboost-atomic1.71-dev libboost-atomic1.71.0 libboost-chrono1.71-dev libboost-chrono1.71.0 libboost-date-time1.71-dev
  libboost-program-options1.71-dev libboost-program-options1.71.0 libboost-serialization1.71-dev libboost-serialization1.71.0
  libboost-system1.71-dev libboost-system1.71.0 libboost-test1.71-dev libboost-test1.71.0 libboost-thread1.71-dev
  libboost1.71-dev
Suggested packages:
  libboost1.71-doc libboost-container1.71-dev libboost-context1.71-dev libboost-contract1.71-dev libboost-coroutine1.71-dev
  libboost-exception1.71-dev libboost-fiber1.71-dev libboost-filesystem1.71-dev libboost-graph1.71-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.71-dev libboost-iostreams1.71-dev libboost-locale1.71-dev libboost-log1.71-dev libboost-math1.71-dev
  libboost-mpi1.71-dev libboost-mpi-python1.71-dev libboost-numpy1.71-dev libboost-python1.71-dev libboost-random1.71-dev
  libboost-regex1.71-dev libboost-stacktrace1.71-dev libboost-timer1.71-dev libboost-type-erasure1.71-dev libboost-wave1.71-dev
  libboost1.71-tools-dev libmpfrc++-dev libntl-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-atomic1.71-dev libboost-atomic1.71.0 libboost-chrono1.71-dev libboost-chrono1.71.0 libboost-date-time1.71-dev
  libboost-program-options-dev libboost-program-options1.71-dev libboost-program-options1.71.0 libboost-serialization1.71-dev
  libboost-serialization1.71.0 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.71-dev libboost-system1.71.0 libboost-test-dev
  libboost-test1.71-dev libboost-test1.71.0 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.71-dev libboost1.71-dev
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 178 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [9,068 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-atomic1.71.0 amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [205 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-atomic1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [205 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-chrono1.71.0 amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [217 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-chrono1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [225 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-serialization1.71.0 amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [302 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-serialization1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [344 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-date-time1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [228 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-program-options1.71.0 amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [342 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-program-options1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [374 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-program-options-dev amd64 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 [3,408 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-system1.71.0 amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [205 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-system1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [205 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-system-dev amd64 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 [3,536 B]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libboost-test1.71.0 amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [437 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libboost-test1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [513 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libboost-test-dev amd64 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 [3,424 B]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-thread1.71-dev amd64 1.71.0-6ubuntu6 [258 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-thread-dev amd64 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 [3,416 B]
Fetched 13.1 MB in 3s (4,006 kB/s)              
Selecting previously unselected package libboost1.71-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 270103 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libboost1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-atomic1.71.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libboost-atomic1.71.0_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-atomic1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-atomic1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libboost-atomic1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-atomic1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-chrono1.71.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libboost-chrono1.71.0_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-chrono1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-chrono1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libboost-chrono1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-chrono1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-serialization1.71.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libboost-serialization1.71.0_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-serialization1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-serialization1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libboost-serialization1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-serialization1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-date-time1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libboost-date-time1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-date-time1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-program-options1.71.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libboost-program-options1.71.0_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-program-options1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-program-options1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libboost-program-options1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-program-options1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-program-options-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libboost-program-options-dev_1.71.0.0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-program-options-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-system1.71.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libboost-system1.71.0_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-system1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-system1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libboost-system1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-system1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-system-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libboost-system-dev_1.71.0.0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-system-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-test1.71.0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libboost-test1.71.0_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-test1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-test1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libboost-test1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-test1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-test-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libboost-test-dev_1.71.0.0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-test-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-thread1.71-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libboost-thread1.71-dev_1.71.0-6ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-thread1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-thread-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libboost-thread-dev_1.71.0.0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-thread-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libboost1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-chrono1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-atomic1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-test1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-serialization1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-system1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-atomic1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-program-options1.71.0:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-program-options1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-chrono1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-system1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-test1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-program-options-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libboost-serialization1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-date-time1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-thread1.71-dev:amd64 (1.71.0-6ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libboost-system-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libboost-test-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libboost-thread-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
6416/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2018] 07:25:21 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ make -j`nproc`
[ 12%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_lib'
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_filesystem"
  (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_filesystemConfig.cmake
    boost_filesystem-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_filesystem" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "boost_filesystem_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "boost_filesystem" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:182 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:443 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:107: caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
6416/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2019] 07:25:24 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
dpkg-query: package 'libboost-dev' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
5694/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2020] 07:26:11 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libprotobuf-lite17 libprotoc17
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  libboost-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libboost-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,596 B of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libboost-dev amd64 1.71.0.0ubuntu2 [3,596 B]
Fetched 3,596 B in 0s (30.4 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 285433 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-dev_1.71.0.0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libboost-dev:amd64 (1.71.0.0ubuntu2) ...
5694/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2021] 07:26:38 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.71.0.0ubuntu2
5741/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2022] 07:26:39 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$ make -j`nproc`
[ 12%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_lib'
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:117 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_filesystem"
  (requested version 1.71.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_filesystemConfig.cmake
    boost_filesystem-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_filesystem" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "boost_filesystem_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "boost_filesystem" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake:182 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:443 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mona/research/code/openpose/build/caffe/src/openpose_lib-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:107: caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
5741/31772MB(openpose) 
[104057:4668 0:2023] 07:26:42 Wed Jan 06 [mona@goku:pts/14 +1] ~/research/code/openpose/build
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks a lot to [R] in IRC channel

```
$ sudo apt install  libboost-filesystem1.71-dev
```